# Does google map android api v2 support street view overlays?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am developing a street view application using google map API, I am not getting any documentation or reference to show overlays on street view, is it supported by google using Android API V2?

I will appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not supported.

StreetView is a separate application that you can launch with an intent but no overlay.

```
google.streetview:cbll=lat,lng&cbp=1,yaw,,pitch,zoom&mz=mapZoom
```

> Opens the Street View application to the given location. The URI
>   scheme is based on the syntax used for Street View panorama
>   information in Google Maps URLs. The cbll field is required. The cbp
>   and mz fields are optional.

(Source: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html)